# Update billing address in checkout page dropdown address

Tags: magento2, checkout, billing-address, magento2.3.4

When update the billing address in magento2 checkout payment page. 
getting below JS error.

replicate for select the dropdown address and click on the update button.
getting below JS error

```
function e(F,E){var D=0;try{this._each(function(H){F.call(E,H,D++)})}catch(G){if(G!=$break){throw G}}return this}, function y(G,F,E){var D=-G,H=[],I=this.toArray();if(G<1){return I}while((D+=G)<I.length){H.push(I.slice(D,D+G))}return H.collect(F,E)}, function d(F,E){F=F||Prototype.K;var D=true;this.each(function(H,G){D=D&&!!F.call(E,H,G);if(!D){throw $break}});return D}, function o(F,E){F=F||Prototype.K;var D=false;this.each(function(H,G){if(D=!!F.call(E,H,G)){throw $break}});return D}, function p(F,E){F=F||Prototype.K;var D=[];this.each(function(H,G){D.push(F.call(E,H,G))});return D}, function A(F,E){var D;this.each(function(H,G){if(F.call(E,H,G)){D=H;throw $break}});return D}, function n(F,E){var D=[];this.each(function(H,G){if(F.call(E,H,G)){D.push(H)}});return D}, function n(F,E){var D=[];this.each(function(H,G){if(F.call(E,H,G)){D.push(H)}});return D}, function l(G,F,E){F=F||Prototype.K;var D=[];if(Object.isString(G)){G=new RegExp(RegExp.escape(G))}this.each(function(I,H){if(G.match(I)){D.push(F.call(E,I,H))}});return D}, function b(D){if(Object.isFunction(this.indexOf)){if(this.indexOf(D)!=-1){return true}}var E=false;this.each(function(F){if(F==D){E=true;throw $break}});return E}, function b(D){if(Object.isFunction(this.indexOf)){if(this.indexOf(D)!=-1){return true}}var E=false;this.each(function(F){if(F==D){E=true;throw $break}});return E}, function w(E,D){D=Object.isUndefined(D)?null:D;return this.eachSlice(E,function(F){while(F.length<E){F.push(D)}return F})}, function r(D,F,E){this.each(function(H,G){D=F.call(E,D,H,G)});return D}, function C(E){var D=$A(arguments).slice(1);return this.map(function(F){return F[E].apply(F,D)})}, function g(G,E){G=G||Prototype.K;var F=[],D=[];this.each(function(I,H){(G.call(E,I,H)?F:D).push(I)});return[F,D]}, function h(E){var D=[];this.each(function(F){D.push(F[E])});return D}, function f(F,E){var D=[];this.each(function(H,G){if(!F.call(E,H,G)){D.push(H)}});return D}, function s(E,D){return this.map(function(G,F){return{value:G,criteria:E.call(D,G,F)}}).sort(function(I,H){var G=I.criteria,F=H.criteria;return G<F?-1:G>F?1:0}).pluck("value")}, function w(){return s.call(this,0)}, function z(){var E=Prototype.K,D=$A(arguments);if(Object.isFunction(D.last())){E=D.pop()}var F=[this].concat(D).map($A);return this.map(function(H,G){return E(F.pluck(G))})}, function p(){return this.length}, function z(){return"["+this.map(Object.inspect).join(", ")+"]"}, function reverse() { [native code] }, function forEach() { [native code] }, function r(){this.length=0;return this}, function f(){return this[0]}, function l(){return this[this.length-1]}, function o(){return this.select(function(B){return B!=null})}, function A(){return this.inject([],function(C,B){if(Object.isArray(B)){return C.concat(B.flatten())}C.push(B);return C})}, function n(){var B=s.call(arguments,0);return this.select(function(C){return !B.include(C)})}, function q(B){return this.inject([],function(E,D,C){if(0==C||(B?E.last()!=D:!E.include(D))){E.push(D)}return E})}, function v(B){return this.uniq().findAll(function(C){return B.detect(function(D){return C===D})})}, function w(){return s.call(this,0)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove _.values for currentBillingAddress().street in 
 in the file vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html
use this in the file `currentBillingAddress().street`
Change this file by copying the file into the app folder with the same path. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

hello great to see someone with the same issue find a solution good work.
I am by no means a coder this is my snippet

Before

**`args="_.values(currentBillingAddress().street).join(', ')"/>`**

After

**`args="(currentBillingAddress().street).join(', ')"/>`**

is this right because i dont really see any change. do I need to run upgrade command?